# using ng-hide to display/hide buttons based on a condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have three buttons in my mark-up two of which are currently being hidden. Like this:

```
<button ng-click="validate()">Submit</button><br />
<button id="retryquiz" ng-hide="true" onclick="location.reload(true);">Retry</button>
<button id="getCertificate" ng-hide="true" onclick="printDoc()">Print Doc</button>
```

Now what I need to do is for ng-hide to somehow evaluate the value coming from the validate() function and based on an "if" statement show one or the other again. For instance, if the result from the validate was more than 50% then it would show Print Doc, and if less than 50% then it would only show the button for Retry.

Just how would I attach the HTML portion of it to my .js file?

Comment: Depending on the exact return value of `validate`, something like `ng-show="validate() > .5"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's best to have a function on your scope that will return a boolean according to your condition, especially when your conditions get more complicated. You can have the condition on your controller or use parameters:

```
<button id="retryquiz" ng-hide="hideRetry()" onclick="location.reload(true);">Retry</button>
```

And in the controller:

```
$scope.hideRetry = function () {
    return $scope.validate() >= 50;
}
```

This way, the "Retry" button will hide if the result from `$scope.validate()` is higher than 50%.

Comment: But what about the initial state? Retry should not be shown right at the start.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg It's just a syntax explanation and approach as he's obviously looking for that. He can then choose to use whatever logic he sees fit.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly when switched to ng-show instead of ng-hide.

Answer (score 2):

Inside validate() set two variable using whatever logic you like, e.g.

```
$scope.showRetryButton = result < 0.5
$scope.showCertificateButton = result > 0.5
```

then in your html

```
<button id="retryquiz" ng-show=showRetryButton ....
<button id="getCertificate" ng-show=showCertificateButton ...
```

you could initialise them both to false in your controller also when you want to hide them again to rerun validate.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will be trying your method as well just to see how many ways will work and so that I can learn something new as well.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend not using a gradient but using explicit states. In your validate function you should set a variable

```
$scope.validate = function(){
  //some work...

  $scope.status == validationResult;
}
```

Then set your `ng-hide`s based on the status:

```
<button id="retryquiz" ng-hide="status=='retry'" onclick="location.reload(true);">Retry</button>
<button id="getCertificate" ng-hide="status=='print'" onclick="printDoc()">Print Doc</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try your method as well!